# Spring messageSource Doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm new to Spring MVC and trying to implement a messageSource.

I have made the following entry in the dispatcher

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/messages"/>
</bean>
```

and I am trying to use it in my jsp like this

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<html>
<body>
<h2><fmt:message key="appName"/></h2>
<h4>
    <a href="${link}"><fmt:message key="login.label"/></a>
</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

However when my page is rendered I get the tag as `???login.label???`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong,
I have kept my messages.properties in the \WEB-INF\classes\ path
and it has a entry like `login.label=Login`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: should'n it be value="/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties"/  ?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the property `basenames` on plural.

```
<property name="basenames">
    <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/classes/messages</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Assuming that your file is named `messages.properties`.

In this case you can use multiples properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply making it `<property name="basename" value="messages"/>` works.